# SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() is returning null

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have this code.

```
public void Insert(Order order)
{
        SqlConnection con = DACHelper.GetConnection();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Orders(Category_Id,Item_Id)Values(@Category_Id,@Item_Id)", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category_Id", order.Category.Id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_Id", order.Item.Id);

        con.Open();

        using (con)
        {
            SqlTransaction tran = con.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Transaction = tran;

            try
            {
                int orderId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                new OrderMailsDAC().Insert(orderId, order.Mail , tran);
                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}

public void Insert(int orderId,OrderConfirmationMail mails,SqlTransaction tran)
{
    SqlConnection con = tran.Connection;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into OrderMails(Mail,Order_Id)Values(@Mail,@Order_Id)", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Transaction = tran;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=mails.Mail;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Order_Id",SqlDbType.Int).Value=orderId;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The problem here is that the

```
int orderId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

is returning null except the `Id` that is stored correctly.

Please help me with this

Comment: The `cmd` doesn't return anything - it just **inserts** a new row into your database. Therefore, the `ExecuteScalar()` will get nothing back ...... are you missing a `;  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` after your `INSERT` statement maybe?? That would return the newly inserted identity value from the `INSERT` statemnet

Answer (score 1):

The ExecuteScalar means that it will return the first cell of your result set. According to that, now look at your command code:

```
"Insert into Orders(Category_Id,Item_Id)Values(@Category_Id,@Item_Id)"
```

You see, it just insert one record into your Orders table, that's it, nothing return.

Therefore, if we want to return the OrderId in case your table has that column, you should modify your command to return that data.

I suggested something like this

```
"Insert into Orders(Category_Id,Item_Id)Values(@Category_Id,@Item_Id); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
```

Comment: @Sajjad You're welcome. Could you please mark this answer? So the others will not post the answer for this question anymore

Answer (score 0):

You have to set output parameter to get new record value in ExecuteScalar

Answer (score 0):

Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

```
  public void Insert(int orderId,OrderConfirmationMail mails,SqlTransaction tran)
     {
SqlConnection con = tran.Connection;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into OrderMails(Mail,Order_Id)Values(@Mail,@Order_Id) " +
                         "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";, con);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.Transaction = tran;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mail", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=mails.Mail;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Order_Id",SqlDbType.Int).Value=orderId;

int insertedId = (int) cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have got the Answer User55 thanks very much
I was Missing SCOPE_Identity()